# Show Element depending on Hour of a day

Tags: javascript, html, css, time, show-hide

How to show/hide elements depending on the current Hour?

- show 1st SPAN from 12:00 to 14:00 (Hide other spans)
- show 2nd SPAN from 17:00 to 03:00 (Hide other spans)
- show 3rd SPAN from 07:00 to 10:00 (Hide other spans)

**Attempt**

```js
var pagi = new Date();   // morning
var siang = new Date();  // day
var malam = new Date();  // night
var time = new Date().getTime();

if (time > pagi.setHours(12, 00)) && time < end.setHours(14, 00)) {
  document.getElementById("malam").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("pagi").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("siang").style.display = "none";
} else if (time > siang.setHours(17, 00) && time < end.setHours(03, 00))) {
  document.getElementById("malam").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("pagi").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("siang").style.display = "none";
} else if (time > malam.setHours(07, 00)) && time < end.setHours(10, 00)) {
  document.getElementById("malam").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("pagi").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("siang").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<span id="malam" style="background-color:magenta;"> malam </span>
<br/>
<span id="pagi" style="background-color:cyan;"> pagi </span>
<br/>
<span id="siang" style="background-color:orange;"> siang </span>
```

Comment: May be use setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getHours()` to the get the local hour and then use conditional statements to display elements accordingly.

```js
let malam = document.getElementById("malam"), 
    pagi = document.getElementById("pagi"),
    siang = document.getElementById("siang"), 
    today, h;

function show(){

  today = new Date(),h = today.getHours();
  
  if(h >= 3){
      if(h>=7 && h<10){
        malam.style.display = 'none';
        pagi.style.display = 'none';
        siang.style.display = 'block';
      }
      else if(h>= 12 && h<14){
        malam.style.display = 'block';
        pagi.style.display = 'none';
        siang.style.display = 'none';
      }
      else if(h>=17){
        malam.style.display = 'none';
        pagi.style.display = 'block';
        siang.style.display = 'none';
      }    
  }else{
      malam.style.display = 'none';
      pagi.style.display = 'block';
      siang.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="malam" style="background-color:magenta; display:none"> malam </p>
<p id="pagi" style="background-color:cyan; display:none"> pagi </p>
<p id="siang" style="background-color:orange; display:none"> siang </p>

<button onclick='show()'>test</button>
```

**Note**: to use *inline event-handling* is not the best practice, if you would like to improve this code use `object.onclick = function(){myScript};` You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Comment: @fauzanrozaq remember to check the answer ;)

Comment: (Offtopic) @Gass Interesting how answerers often remind question authors to *"checkmark"* their answer but somehow the same ones do not upvote good questions that show research, effort, and the minimal code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Given that you haven't explained your code in order to teach the OP anything about *why*, or *how*, this might work you've also introduced a button that isn't in the original code which requires an interaction (with no explanation as to why it's there, or why it's required), and you've used inline event-handling which is itself poor practice. This is, of course, purely my opinion and you can update/explain - or not - as you feel appropriate, but I'm not sure why you'd believe this answer - as written - deserves to be accepted as the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array of objects and extract the one that matches the array index `0, 1, 2, 3` given the current hour of a day. And drastically simplify your HTML as well:

```js
const h = new Date().getHours();
const dp = [
  {text: "morning", bg: "cyan"},      // From 07 to 10
  {text: "day",     bg: "orange"},    // From 12 to 14
  {text: "night",   bg: "magenta"},   // From 17 to 03
  {text: "",        bg: "none"},      // All other hours
][
  h >=  7 && h < 10 ? 0 :
  h >= 12 && h < 14 ? 1 :
  h >= 17 && h <  3 ? 2 :
                      3
];

const EL_dayPeriod = document.querySelector("#dayPeriod");
EL_dayPeriod.textContent      = dp.text; 
EL_dayPeriod.style.background = dp.bg;
```

```html
<span id="dayPeriod"></span>
```

Comment: I do like the answer, except for the horrible nested ternary; regardless of that, though, have an upvote!

Comment: @david Thank you! PS: just to stand in defense :D of a [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) I would not (subjectively speaking) call it *that horrible* :)   I think it's *arguably* pretty decent actually. At least in comparison with: https://jsfiddle.net/xravtc6k/ and given Ternary operators are basic CS101.

Answer (score 0):

you are using same time for pagi, siang  and malam. So you can do it with single vairable in following way.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var pagiT = new Date();
            var time = new Date().getTime();

            if (time > pagiT.setHours(14, 00)) {
                document.getElementById("malam").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("pagi").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("siang").style.display = "none";
            }
            else if (time < pagiT.setHours(03, 00)) {
                document.getElementById("malam").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("pagi").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("siang").style.display = "none";
            }
            else  {
                document.getElementById("malam").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("pagi").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("siang").style.display = "block";
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple sample with [setTimeout()](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval)

```js
var malam = document.getElementById("malam")
  var pagi = document.getElementById("pagi")
  var siang = document.getElementById("siang")
  
 setTimeout(showMalam, 3000);

  function showMalam(){
    console.log("showMalam caled at: " +  (new Date()));
    malam.style.display = "block";
    pagi.style.display = "none";
    siang.style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(showPagi, 3000);
  }
  function showPagi(){
    console.log("showPagi caled at: " +  (new Date()));
    malam.style.display = "none";
    pagi.style.display = "block";
    siang.style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(showSiang, 3000);
  }
  function showSiang(){
    console.log("showSiang caled at: " +  (new Date()));
    malam.style.display = "none";
    pagi.style.display = "none";
    siang.style.display = "block";
   }
```

```html
<span id="malam" style="background-color:magenta;"> malam </span>
<br/>
<span id="pagi" style="background-color:cyan;display:none"> pagi </span>
<br/>
<span id="siang" style="background-color:orange;display:none"> siang </span>
```

Comment: i mean not that ,  when time ...

-show only 12.00 -14.00 id "malam" show, other id hide.
-show only 17.00 - 03.00 id "pagi" show, other id hide.
-show 07.00 - 10.00 span "siang" show, other id hide.

Comment: You can play around with current time and then see when to timeout for we e.g now it's 9 and set timeout could be 2 hours from now